# User profile keeping old records and add endDate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have this table CustomerProfile that has the CustomerId, ProfileId,startDate and endDate. When the user add data to the profile it will insert a record with a startDate and endDate is null. If the user edit the profile I want to see if they make a change so I need to count the record in the table and if it not 0 then I do a check if that option has changed. In the BEGIN section do I need to select the ProfileId and see if it different? can I do that in the CountCustomerProfileId? Any help with this would be great.

Insert default values

```
insert into [dbo].[CustomerProfile] (CustomerId,ProfileId,startDate,endDate)
values (1,2,2022-09-07,null)
```

Counts that the users has insert data in the profile table before

```
DECLARE @CountCustomerProfileId INT
SET @CountCustomerProfileId = (SELECT Count([CustomerProfileId]) as CustomerProfileId
        FROM [dbo].[CustomerProfile]
        where [CustomerId] = @CustomerId)
```

BEGIN Code:  ProfileId "2,3"

```
IF @CustomerProfileId > 0
    BEGIN
    
        UPDATE [dbo].[CustomerProfile] set endDate = GETDATE() 
        WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
    END
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26d992/5

Comment: "*In the BEGIN section do I need to select the ProfileId and see if it different?*" - What do you mean by this? What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: the ultimate goal is set a endDate on the old value if they are not the same id. If the id are the same I dont need to do anything.